# Creating SwiftData Model instances very slow

Tags: ios, swift, model, macros, swift-data

> UPDATE: I used one of my "code-level support" tickets with Apple. Sent
> a test project along with test data. Their response "There is no
> workaround DTS can provide for Feedback ID #FB13432637; it is still
> under investigation. Please continue to track the problem via the bug
> report."

Is SwiftData not designed for large datasets?
How to create many instances of my Data Model?

I have a loop where I iterate over a CSV file of 30k+ lines. Totalling around 230k elements. I intend to save this data into SwiftData. However it takes around 90 seconds. In previous versions of my app I was using coreData. Then it took just 3 seconds. So after much investigation I have concluded the delay comes from creating instances of the Data Model.
To Test this I have :

- Removed any saves into SwiftData. So only creation of the Model Object occurs.
- Created an exact copy of the SwiftData Model class but admitted the @Model macro
- set `isAutosaveEnabled` to false

When I run my loop with the copy class it takes 3 seconds. So It must be creating the SwiftData model instances that causes the *30 delay.

The code using swiftData @Model. This loop takes 90+ seconds to complete

```swift
@Model
class TimetableData {
    
    var arrivalTime : Int = 0
    var departureTime: Int = 0
    var departureRoute : Int = 0
    var directionOfTravel : Int = 0
    var dutyNumber : Int = 0
    var facilityIdentifier : String = ""
    var locationType : String = ""
    var mode : String = ""
    var nonStopStatus : Int = 0
    var recordIdentifier : String = ""
    var timetableIdentifier : Int = 0
    var trainNumber : String = ""
    var tripNumber : Int = 0
    var tripStartSite : String = ""
    var uniqueLocationCode : String = ""
    
    init(arrivalTime: Int = 0, departureTime: Int = 0, departureRoute: Int = 0, directionOfTravel: Int = 0, dutyNumber: Int = 0, facilityIdentifier: String = "", locationType: String = "", mode: String = "", nonStopStatus: Int = 0, recordIdentifier: String = "", timetableIdentifier: Int = 0, trainNumber: String = "", tripNumber: Int = 0, tripStartSite: String = "", uniqueLocationCode: String = "") {
        
        self.name = name
        self.arrivalTime = arrivalTime
        self.departureTime = departureTime
        self.departureRoute = departureRoute
        self.directionOfTravel = directionOfTravel
        self.dutyNumber = dutyNumber
        self.facilityIdentifier = facilityIdentifier
        self.locationType = locationType
        self.mode = mode
        self.nonStopStatus = nonStopStatus
        self.recordIdentifier = recordIdentifier
        self.timetableIdentifier = timetableIdentifier
        self.trainNumber = trainNumber
        self.tripNumber = tripNumber
        self.tripStartSite = tripStartSite
        self.uniqueLocationCode = uniqueLocationCode
    }
}

for line in CSVFile {
    
    var columnValue = line.components(separatedBy: ",")
    
    let timeTableDataEntry  = TimetableData (
        
        arrivalTime: Int(columnValue[0])!,
        departureTime: Int(columnValue[1])!,
        departureRoute: Int(columnValue[2])!,
        directionOfTravel: Int(columnValue[3])!,
        dutyNumber: Int(columnValue[4])!,
        facilityIdentifier: columnValue[5],
        locationType: columnValue[6],
        mode: columnValue[7],
        nonStopStatus: Int(columnValue[8])!,
        recordIdentifier:  columnValue[9],
        timetableIdentifier: Int(columnValue[10])!,
        trainNumber: columnValue[11],
        tripNumber: Int(columnValue[12])!,
        tripStartSite: columnValue[13],
        uniqueLocationCode:columnValue[14]
    )
}
```

Then The exact same code but omitting the @Model takes around just 3 second.

```swift
class TimetableDataForTesting {
    
    var arrivalTime : Int = 0
    var departureTime: Int = 0
    var departureRoute : Int = 0
    var directionOfTravel : Int = 0
    var dutyNumber : Int = 0
    var facilityIdentifier : String = ""
    var locationType : String = ""
    var mode : String = ""
    var nonStopStatus : Int = 0
    var recordIdentifier : String = ""
    var timetableIdentifier : Int = 0
    var trainNumber : String = ""
    var tripNumber : Int = 0
    var tripStartSite : String = ""
    var uniqueLocationCode : String = ""
    
    init(arrivalTime: Int = 0, departureTime: Int = 0, departureRoute: Int = 0, directionOfTravel: Int = 0, dutyNumber: Int = 0, facilityIdentifier: String = "", locationType: String = "", mode: String = "", nonStopStatus: Int = 0, recordIdentifier: String = "", timetableIdentifier: Int = 0, trainNumber: String = "", tripNumber: Int = 0, tripStartSite: String = "", uniqueLocationCode: String = "") {
        
        self.name = name
        self.arrivalTime = arrivalTime
        self.departureTime = departureTime
        self.departureRoute = departureRoute
        self.directionOfTravel = directionOfTravel
        self.dutyNumber = dutyNumber
        self.facilityIdentifier = facilityIdentifier
        self.locationType = locationType
        self.mode = mode
        self.nonStopStatus = nonStopStatus
        self.recordIdentifier = recordIdentifier
        self.timetableIdentifier = timetableIdentifier
        self.trainNumber = trainNumber
        self.tripNumber = tripNumber
        self.tripStartSite = tripStartSite
        self.uniqueLocationCode = uniqueLocationCode
    }
}

for line in CSVFile {
    
    var columnValue = line.components(separatedBy: ",")
    
    let timeTableDataEntry  = TimetableDataForTesting (
        
        arrivalTime: Int(columnValue[0])!,
        departureTime: Int(columnValue[1])!,
        departureRoute: Int(columnValue[2])!,
        directionOfTravel: Int(columnValue[3])!,
        dutyNumber: Int(columnValue[4])!,
        facilityIdentifier: columnValue[5],
        locationType: columnValue[6],
        mode: columnValue[7],
        nonStopStatus: Int(columnValue[8])!,
        recordIdentifier:  columnValue[9],
        timetableIdentifier: Int(columnValue[10])!,
        trainNumber: columnValue[11],
        tripNumber: Int(columnValue[12])!,
        tripStartSite: columnValue[13],
        uniqueLocationCode:columnValue[14]
    )
}
```

Comment: Try turning off `autoSave` on your model context

Comment: Thanks. Just tried as suggested. Unfortunately didn't have any affect. Will Update my post to reflect

Comment: Is the csv fixed and included in your bundle or is it downloaded at runtime?  If it is fixed, you can just load the data and ship the core data files in your bundle and copy them into place on the first launch.

Comment: I guess the most effective solution is to go back to using Core Data then. Hopefully SwiftData performance will improve and also that there will be some kind of batch insert functionality in the future like we have in Core Data today.